# Adjust margins on certain pages of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

My University requires the first page of the table of contents to have 2 inch margins at the top and the subsequent pages to have a 1 inch margin at the top. All of the remaining pages in this section should have 2 inch margins.

Currently I have

```
\begin{doublespace}
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\@abstract

%\chapter*{DEDICATION}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DEDICATION} 

%\@dedication

%% Print everything in the glossary.
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS AND SYMBOLS}]
\glsresetall

%\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}


%\@acknowledgments

\tableofcontents


\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES} 

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES} 
\end{doublespace}
\restoregeometry
```

I have been trying to place `\afterpage{\newgeometry{top=1in}}` and a few other tags before the `\tableofcontents`, however I can't seem to figure it out.
I'm brand new to LaTeX and have attempted to read some related questions without luck.

Comment: Why can't you just put \newgeometry{top=1in} immediately before the \tableofcontents?

Comment: Side note: Your entries for the list of figures/tables and the entry for the toc itself are wrong.

Comment: Adding \newgeometry{top=1in} before and \newgeometry{top=2in} after is giving me two issues. I get a blank page before the table of contents and another after. Also the first page of the TOC only has a 1in margin where I want the first page to have 2in and the subsequent pages to have 1in. @JohnKormylo

Comment: Can you expand upon that @Johannes_B? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You add the entry when the whole list was already output. If the list is longer than one page, you get the last pagenumber in the toc.

Comment: By 2in margin do they mean the space from the top of the page to the top of "Table of Contents", because there is already an extra 60pt margin below the top of the text area.